# Support IE 11 using browserslist and babel

Tags: internet-explorer-11, babeljs, polyfills

I already have this in my `.babelrc`:

```
  presets: [
    [
      'env',
      {
        targets: {
          browsers:   'last 2 versions, > 5%'
        },
        modules:      false,
        useBuiltIns:  'entry',
        debug:        true
      }
    ]
  ]
```

Now I want to support IE 11 too. So I added `IE 11` to the `browsers` string. But when I test it I still see an error related to custom events for example. Adding a polyfill for it, fixes it. But then I'm seeing another error.

When I run the script I'm seeing:

```
Using targets:
{
  "chrome": "65",
  "android": "4.4.3",
  "edge": "16",
  "firefox": "59",
  "ie": "10",
  "ios": "11",
  "safari": "11"
}
```

I don't want to manually add polyfills for each feature. Anyone knows if adding IE 11 to the browsers string should fix it?

Comment: I think in your `browsers` you could simply add `ie 11`. Did it fix the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Should your browsers be: "last 2 versions, > 0.5%, ie >= 11"

So you force ie to be 11 or higher while all o